# Using gAlwaysIdle in Linux

Tags: linux, gmail

I recent came across an application called gAlwaysIdle.

Can anyone tell me how to use it for Linux? It doesn't work with Wine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide a link or any details on what it is or where it came from or what kind of specific problems you're having.

However, [here's a link](http://code.google.com/p/python-galwaysidle/) to a Python script called `galwaysidle.py` that purports to work in Linux to set your GMail Chat status to "idle".